# Dimension of set of planes

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ax +by + cz$ = $0$ be a plane through the origin. Show that the dimension of this plane as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $2$.

What I tried: I tried looking for a basis for the set of all planes that satisfy $ax +by + cz = 0$ and finding the number of elements in the basis. I know how to prove a set is a basis for another set, I just am confused about how to find the proper basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that an element $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}$ is in the plane if, and only if
$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\cdot\pmatrix{a\\b\\c} = 0,$$
so your plane is given by the set of all vectors that are orthogonal to the vector $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: so you're talking about the set of vectors crossed with $\langle a,b,c \rangle$? What is a basis for that set?

Comment: @Raton You don't have a canonical choice. Just pick two that are linearly independent. In fact, you can pick one and its cross product with $(a,b,c)$ if you prefer.

Comment: @Raton No, I mean that you can pick one vector, and then get the second one automatically by crossing the first one with $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: How do you figure out the number of elements in that set, though?

Comment: @Raton I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I'm just confused about how to come up with a basis for the set containing orthogonal vectors to a plane going through the origin.

Comment: @Raton Once you have found your two vectors $v_1,v_2$ that are linearly independent and orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$, it is easy to show that $v_1,v_2,(a,b,c)$ are again linearly independent and thus form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore (as your plane is a linear subspace that is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$), $v_1,v_2$ are a basis of the plane. Otherwise, you can see the plane as the kernel of a matrix associated to $(a,b,c)$, and it will be easy to compute its dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a great teacher.

Comment: @Raton Thanks! :)